# Unable to git push on local repository

Tags: git

Git-1.7.11-preview20120710.exe used by me. I create a git repository

```
cd "GIT scm/"
git init --bare shahed.git
cd shahed.git
git update-server-info
```

Then I start git daemon by following command

```
git daemon --reuseaddr --base-path="E:/GIT scm/" --export-all --verbose --enable=receive-pack
```

Then I clone the git repository as following

```
git clone git://localhost/shahed.git

Cloning into 'shahed'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

cd shahed
touch shahed.txt
touch shohel.txt
git add *.*
git commit -m 'ok'

[master (root-commit) 2062f1d] 'ok'
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 shahed.txt
 create mode 100644 shohel.txt

git push

No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
Everything up-to-date
```

While git daemon console log following message

```
[4044] Ready to rumble
[736] Connection from [::1]:50076
[736] Extended attributes (16 bytes) exist <host=localhost>
[736] Request upload-pack for '/shahed.git'
[4044] [736] Disconnected
[4860] Connection from [::1]:50079
[4860] Extended attributes (16 bytes) exist <host=localhost>
[4860] Request receive-pack for '/shahed.git'
[4860] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

But I am unable to git push. anybody tell me which step i missed to creating git repository. all the initiative are taken by me are ok or where is the lackings for configuring git repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What that is telling you is that there is no `master` branch in your bare `origin` repository, because it was created empty. So, it can't find the branch you want to update, and by default it won't blindly create a new branch (in case it was a typo or something). You may need to use `git push -f origin master` the first time. Once there is a `master` branch in `origin`, normal `git push` should work fine.

Alternatively, you could create your working repository first, with at least one commit in it, then `git clone --bare` it into your `git-daemon` location, but you'll then want to remove the `origin` remote specification in your bare repository, and you'll have to manually add it (or re-clone) in your working repository.

Comment: I tested as you answered but unable create master branch both repository creation/clone time. i used force option but not work. `git push -f origin master` it takes long time, finally i terminate it by force.

Comment: That sounds more like an issue with your `git-daemon` configuration or a firewall setting or something. I manually recreated your test, and `git push origin master` definitely worked for me (but an unqualified `git push` didn't.

Comment: Firewall unblocked. So far I could guess something lackings / miss configuration/ some issue related with path setting. Would you refer me some web link from where I will start again?

Comment: I've always found the various documentation/tutorial/etc. links off [this site](http://www.git-scm.com) to be useful.